# Ionic2/Angular2 : Empty [(ngModel)] value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm having trouble passing value from the template to the component.
I'm getting json response, which I display into the view.
I want to pass one orderId value to the function getOrderbyId.
But I got undefined value...

Here is my .html:

```
(...)
    <ion-item (click)="getOrderById()">
      <!-- TODO: OrderbyId not passing id -->
        <p primary>Dernière commande :
          N°{{response?.last_order_id}}
        </p>
        <em>Du {{response?.last_order_date}}</em>
        <!-- Input to pass orderid for the getOrderById() -->
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="orderId"/>
    </ion-item>
(...)
```

My .ts:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core'
import {CustomerService} from './customers.service';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/ecommerce/customers/customers.html',
  providers: [CustomerService]
})
export class CustomersPage {

  response:string;
  keyword:string;
  results:string [];
  allCustomers:boolean = false;
  http;
  orderId:string;

  constructor(public nav: NavController,  httpService:Http, private customerService:CustomerService) {
    this.customerService = customerService;
    this.http = httpService;
    this.keyword = '';
  }

  getCustomerbyEmail() {
      this.customerService.getCustomersById(this.keyword)
      .subscribe(
          response => this.response = response,
          error => console.log(error));
  }

  getOrderById() {
this.customerService.getOrderById(this.orderId)
.subscribe(
    response => {
        this.response = response; 
        this.orderId = response.last_order_id;
    },
    error => console.log(error));
```

}
    }

And finally the service:

```
(...)
getOrderById(id) : Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    return this._http.get(this._url+'orders/'+id+this.urlBase, {
      headers : headers
    }).map(res => res.json().customer);
  }
(...)
```

I don't understand why I'm not getting any values from the [(ngModel)]="orderId"...

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks.
Yin.

Comment: What is `value="{{response?.last_order_id}}"` supposed to do? What value do you want to get. The one assigned with this code or the one entered by the user?

Comment: I want the value assigned with this code, it's a orderId I am getting from the json response.

Comment: Why don't you assign it to `this.orderId`, the one `[(ngModel)]="userId"` is pointing to?

Comment: I'm already doing it in the getOrderById() but it returns undefined...

Comment: Found something interesting: if I fire the getOrderById() without touching the value in the input it's undefined. But if I delete it and type it again, it works...Is this the normal behaviour?

Comment: Did you remove the `value=...` already. I wouldn't this to do anything useful.

Comment: No I need the value, coming from the json request.Just to be clear(sorry for my bad english) first, I have a getUser method, which returns an object(in which the {{response?.last_order_id}} is).Then, on click is called the getOrderById() method with this {{response?.last_order_id}} in param. Thanks for your patience...

Comment: Just assign it to `userId`. 2-way binding `[(ngModel)]="userId"` will take care of the rest and you can drop `value=...`

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, but how do I do that? In the constructor of the .ts? Really have no idea...

Comment: Where you do  `this.response = response`. Change it to `{this.response = response; this.orderId = response.last_order_id;}`. Sorry only on my phone therefore the short responses.

Comment: No excuses please I'm so glad to have your help. I've added this code, but I the value is not present (undefined)...I modified the above code to match yours...

Comment: I'll have another lool tomorrow. Time for bed here.

Comment: When you also print the value `console.log(response.last_order_id)` (where you have `this.response = response;`), does it print the expected `last_order_id` value?

Comment: It prints nothing, this is how I implemented it : getOrderById() {
    this.customerService.getOrderById(this.orderId)
    .subscribe(
        response => {this.response = response; this.orderId = response.last_order_id;
          console.log(response.last_order_id)},
        error => console.log(error));
  }

Comment: Wouldn't you expect it to have a value? Seems to be an issue with client/server communication?

Comment: I have no way to debug what the server returns. You can enter the url the service makes the request to manually to the browser and investigate the response if it contains a value for `last_order_id`

Comment: I see no way to help you with this. I don't know what the server does or why it doesn't return what you expect. This needs to be fixed to continue the `ngModel` issue though.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I'll let you know if I find a solution.